# Force a full domain name in param

Tags: powershell

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true , HelpMessage = "Enter a domain like facebook.com")]

    [ValidateScript({
            try {

                $_ -like "*.*" 
            }
            catch {

                throw "Enter a domain like facebook.com."

            }
        })][string]$Domain
)
```

I am trying to learn to error check in param. I know how to do this in a `if` .
From what I read this should work but when sent Facebook I get the error below.
It works for facebook.com

error

```
Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Domain'. The "
            try {
                $_ -like "*.*" 
            }
            catch {
                throw "Enter a domain like facebook.com."
            }
        " validation script for the argument with value "facebook" did not return a result of True. Determine why the validation script failed,  
and then try the command again.
At line:1 char:1
+ . {
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current `try` statement will not throw an error, so it will never run `catch`. You could also throw a better error type

Your validation script should look closer to this:

```
param(
  [ValidateScript({
    if ($_ -like "*.*") {
      $true
    }
    else {
      Throw [System.Management.Automation.ValidationMetadataException] "Enter a domain like facebook.com."
    }
  })][string]$Domain
)
```

You can use try/catch in validation scripts, but only if the actual try block returns an error

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ValidatePattern` with regex

```
 [ValidatePattern('.*\..*')]
```

In Powershell 7 the `ErrorMessage` parameter was added

```
 [ValidatePattern('.*\..*', ErrorMessage = "your message")]
```

Comment: I am also trying to control the error message.

Comment: you can use `ErrorMessage` to provide custom messages with validate parameters, i edited my answer :)

Comment: ```Property 'ErrorMessage' cannot be found for type 'System.Management.Automation.ValidatePatternAttribute'.
At line:6 char:6
+     ][ValidatePattern('.*\..*', ErrorMessage = "your message")][strin ...
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFoundForType```

Comment: sorry, should have added that this functionality is only available in powershell 7